# Delphi: what are the 8 mystery components on my form?

Tags: delphi

When I iterate of the controls on my form, I see those which I placed there at design time or run time.  They are all of type TEdit, Tmemo, TComboBox, etc ...

However, there are always exactly eight which I do not recognize. I can skip over them, since they are not of a type which interests me, but I am curios.

I am guessing system controls like min/max/close. Their Name property is empty. Is there any way I can determine what type they are (without explicitly testing for every standard component derived from TWinControl) ?

I am curious - but not yellow ;-)

---

```
for i := 0 to Form1.ControlCount -1 do ...
```

---

Answer:  use `ClassName` to find out. And i got `TGrabHandle` for all of them.

Thanks for all the help. +! all round

Comment: With delphi 2007, ControlCount matches the number of VCL controls; min/max/close are not included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use their `ClassName` to get an idea of wht they are when the Name property is empty.

Comment: you said first, by one minute, so you get the answer (sorry @Neftalí, but you did get +1 for your answer and twice for your comments ;-)

Answer edited into question for better formatting.

Answer (score 2):

TObject has the property ClassName; Try to access and interrogate this property for this components.
Paste the code block (for/while) that you are using for interrogate the form, for search components.

Regards

Comment: for i := 0 to Form1.ControlCount -1 do ...
  as stated, their names are empty string

Comment: then are you using Form1.Control[i] to access them?

Comment: yes, I am (but I need min 15 chars to say that, else I'm not allowed to post)